# Microsoft Graph API token's scope is different from the ones set in the Azure portal

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

By using jwt.io I managed to determine the token my app acquires for Microsoft Graph API only contains the scopes for Directory.Read.All and User.Read:

[image]

And this is different from the permissions I set in the Azure portal which contains a lot more scopes, such as User.ReadBasic.All:

[image]

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Check out the service principals grants via [Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net). Find your app's principal under `/servicePrincipals`, then check `/servicePrincipals/object-id/oauth2PermissionGrants`. This will tell you which delegated permissions have been authorized for the app.

Comment: @juunas can you put up the full request link for the graph explorer please, sorry I'm still new to microsoft graph

Comment: Wow, the Graph Explorer has been updated just now.. So the new address is actually https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/. You will have to sign in there, and then type something like this into the text box: `https://graph.windows.net/myazuread.onmicrosoft.com/servicePrincipals`, and then hit Go. And by the way, this explorer is for Azure AD Graph API, not Microsoft Graph API. Different APIs. But the point here is to check permission grants for your app in Azure AD.

Comment: @juunas there wasn't a property called `oauth2PermissionGrants` but only `oauth2Permissions` however it doesn't display any scope in the json, only admin and user consent description displaying a very vague discription of `"adminConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access AppName on behalf of the signed-in user."`

Comment: That's the wrong thing :) Those are the permissions provided by your app, not the ones it is *using*. Once you find your principal, change the URL in the text box to e.g. `https://graph.windows.net/myazuread.onmicrosoft.com/servicePrincipals/service-principal-object-id/oauth2PermissionGrants`. Just grab the *objectId* of the service principal and replace *service-principal-object-id* with it. These grants are a navigation property and are not visible there on the principal itself.

Comment: @juunas is there a way to filter the `serviceprincipal` json data? I'm getting way too many and can't seem to find the one for my app

Comment: Yes, actually. If you know the display name, you can do this: `https://graph.windows.net/myazuread.onmicrosoft.com/servicePrincipals?$filter=displayName eq 'My App Name'`. Replace *My App Name* with your app's display name. Wish you could do a contains query, but that function is not allowed :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see this commonly when you go back to your app and add additional permissions AFTER a user has already logged in and consented to your app. That user continues to get the "old" permissions, but new users would get the new set.

If my guess is right, then you probably originally registered the app with just `Directory.Read.All` and `User.Read`. You logged in with your user account. You then went and added additional permissions and tried again. Does that sound right?

The problem is that Azure's v1 endpoints don't dynamically update the scopes for users that have already consented. You need to force a "re-consent" experience for these users. Add a `prompt=consent` parameter to your authorize URL. That should cause the user to see the consent screen again with the updated list of permissions.

Comment: Sorry I'm still quite new to this, I've just added my code of getting the token in the edit and I'm not sure where to add the `prompt=consent` inside the code

Comment: Well ADAL has a few different versions. Which one are you using?

Comment: I think it's 2.14 as that's what it says in the Nuget package manager

Comment: Ok. I need to see where you do the actual user login. The code you've pasted there uses `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` which means you've already logged in. Is this a web app? Are you using OWIN for login?

Comment: `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` came with the `Active.Directory` Nuget Package. For login, I used the built-in `Configure Azure AD Authentication` from Visual Studio for my web app. I've added my code from `Startup.Auth` to see if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just got the global administrator of our azure portal to re-grant the permissions!